# Finding turning point through differenciation

Tags: derivatives

Homework question. Having a little trouble. My attempt is below.

Find the turning points of the following function

**f(x) = 6x^4 – 8x^3 + 5**

dy/dx   = 24x^3 – 24x^2 
    = 24x^2(x – 1)
    = (24x^2)(x – 1)
    = 24x^2 = 0, x – 1 = 0
    = x = 0, x = 1

x = 0,  f(0) = 6(0^4) – 8(0^3) + 5
    f(0) = 5

x = 0, y = 5    (0,5)

d^2y/dx^2 = 72x2 – 48x

x = 0, 72(0^2) – 48(0)
x = 0, d^2y/dx^2 = 0

x = 1,  f(1) = 6(1^4) – 8(1^3) + 5
    f(1) = 3

x = 1, y = 3    (1,3)

Am i on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think taking the first derivative and some observation will do.

$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=24x^2(x-1)$$

$x^2$ will always stay non-negative. So, just consider $x-1$. At $x=1$ the sign would flip. So, there would be only one turning point.

Comment: Yes, This is the way its shown in my course text. Through this method I got a point (1,3) which I believe is a turning point.  When I get the second derivative of it, I get 24 which tells me its the local minimum.  Is this correct?

Comment: absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

for the turning Points you will Need the second derivative this is 
$$f''(x)=72x^2-48x$$ solving $$f''(x)=0$$ we get $$x_1=0$$ or $$x_2=\frac{2}{3}$$
and since $$f'''(x)=144x-48$$ and $$f'''(0)=-48\ne 0$$ and $$f'''\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=48\ne 0$$ we have two turning points

Comment: Really dont understand where alot of that came from. Is a turning point not where the first deriative = 0, not the second

Comment: see here http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Calculus/stationary_points.htm